# How to Deploy multiple python flask apps to a single azure app service?

Tags: python, azure, azure-web-app-service

I want to deploy multiple apps to a single Azure app service (Linux). These apps are related but independently developed by different groups and have to deployed to a single app service. In the windows+dotnet world we could achieve this by deploying to virtual folders. Trying find a way to achieve the same with python on Linux app service. Any guidance is appreciated.

I am trying to achieve similar to that of virtual folders  - but with Python Flask and Azure App Services
domain.com/api1
domain.com/api2
domain.com/api3
...
each of the apis are developed by different groups and should be deployed independently..

Answer (score 2):

App service plans are the 'servers' in this instance so they provide the CPU and memory. App services or 'web apps' are the sites you are connecting too.

In the App service you can go to the path mappings tab under configuration and setup custom storage. However I am not sure this will meet your needs [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common#configure-path-mappings)

However I think the better option is to create an App service per application unless there is a need for them to share a main directory / domain name as it doesn't cost any more and separates them out for configuration, network settings etc.

Comment: thanks... that's a good way to look at plans vs apps. What I am trying to achieve is more like virtual folders in windows web servers. domain.com/api1 domain.com/api2 domain.com/api3
with multiple web apps - it's more like api1.domain.com, api2.domain.com, etc.. which presents additional challenges integrating .. like CORS, etc.

Comment: Windows app services have this exact feature the problem is using linux. I have not personally gone through and setup the custom storage to see how that works but it could be a solution. If not, you may have to either use windows or containerise your services.